# Bash Script Loop Issue

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh

I tried to use array elements from a loop as dynamic key for select related arrays. i tried several methods but internal loops does not work and i can't use parent argument as dynamic key for select correct array.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash

SUFFIX='.zip'
ZIPCOMMAND=""
DSTDIR="/root/destfiles/"
SRCDIR="/root/srcfiles"
ZIPCOMMAND=""
PACKAGES=("STARTER" "BUSINESS")
STARTER=("209" "Module2")
BUSINESS=("210" "Module1" "Module3")

# packageid, destination command
function make_zip_file {
   targetfilename="${2}${1}$(echo -n "${1}" | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1 ).zip ${3}"
    echo "$targetfilename"
}
cd $SRCDIR
declare -p BUSINESS
for j in "${PACKAGES[@]}"; do
    COUNT=0;
    declare -p j
    nums=${#j[@]}
    echo "$nums";
    if (( $nums > 1 )); then
        for i in "${j[@]}"; do
               if ((  $COUNT == 0 )); then
                               Packageid=$i;
                               echo -e "Package id $Packageid";
               else
                      echo -e "# $COUNT - $i$SUFFIX"
                      ZIPCOMMAND="${ZIPCOMMAND} ${i}${SUFFIX}";
                         fi
               COUNT=$(($COUNT+1));
        done
        echo -e "$ZIPCOMMAND"
        ZIPPARAMS=$(make_zip_file "$Packageid" "$DSTDIR" "$ZIPCOMMAND")
        zip -qr $ZIPPARAMS
        echo -e "$ZIPPARAMS"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking for a way to dereference the arrays `STARTER` and `BUSINESS` using the variable `j`.

Perhaps there's a better way, but what I do is:

```
jref="${j}[@]"
jarray=("${!jref}")
```

Example:

```
$ BUSINESS=("210" "Module1" "Module3")
$ j=BUSINESS
$ jref="${j}[@]"
$ jarray=("${!jref}")
$ printf "%s\n" "${jarray[@]}"
210
Module1
Module3
$ echo ${jarray[1]}
Module1
```